# Breaking bonds with magnetic fields

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, molecular-structure, molecules

I was wondering if we could break a bond by applying a big magnetic field on a molecule. The magnetic would just cause the spin of cores of the atoms making the molecule to be aligned , raising the energy of molecular bonding orbital in the same energy of the antibonding molecular orbital allowing an electron to hop from the molecular bonding orbital to the molecular antibonding orbital destroying the molecule.

Comment: You'll need a field bigger than just big.

Comment: Well, aromatic systems tend to align in a strong magnetic field. LC systems. You can make a fragile molecule where this alignment ruptures a bond. *Why* anybody would want to do that is beyond my imagination. ;)

Comment: Extreme magnetic fields can do interesting things (though not turn to steel while attempting time travel, if you're catching my drift) but "cause the spin of cores of the atoms" is, at very least, not a proper wording.

Comment: cause the spin of the cores of atoms aligned.